# Difference between service registry vs service broker?

Tags: service, registry, soa

What is the between **service registry** vs **service broker** in serice oriented archetecture?

Answer (score 0):

SOA registry is responsible for registering business services, while SOA broker is responsible for orchestrating the connections between these components.. The service broker reads the interface information from the registry and then makes the right connection to other interfaces.